# I deleted an object and attempt to save it again but Rails does not allow it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, destroy

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and when I'm trying to build a simple web app, I stumbled this error:

- I have 2 models: User and Post
- User can have many posts
  I created a user(`user1`) and a post(`post1`) associated with that user:

```
     user1: #<User:0x00007fb82d27d3b8
  id: 1,
  username: "Thao",
  password: nil,
  email: nil,
  age: nil,
  created_at: Mon, 03 Jul 2023 01:13:07.787945000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 03 Jul 2023 01:13:07.787945000 UTC +00:00,
  phone_number: nil>

    post1: #<Post:0x00007fb82cc2f038
 id: 1,
 content: "hi this is my first post",
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Mon, 03 Jul 2023 02:18:35.058605000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 03 Jul 2023 02:18:35.058605000 UTC +00:00>
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { in: 2..20 }

    has_many :posts
end

    class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

- Later, I deleted the post with `post1.destroy`. When I tried to save it again with `post1.save`, it returned `false` , though `post1.valid?` returned `true` and `post1.errors` returned an empty array. I tried `post1.save!` and it just returned `Failed to save the record (ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved)`. I also did not have any callback methods.
- Can anyone tell me why this happened ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post1` object has the id's value.

You use the method `.save` so the query will be generated is

`UPDATE ... where id = 1` not `CREATE ...`

Solution:

```
post1.dup.save
```

P/S: You should read more about [persistence](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html)
You can try to create an object by `.new` instead of using deleted object and then `save` to see the query.

### UPDATE

in case, you really want to re-create / restore the old object `post1`

```
restore_post1 = post1.dup
restore_post1.assign_attributes(id: post1.id)
restore_post1.save
```

Comment: thank you for your response @Lee Drum. I tried your solution and it worked. But I noticed that the `id` has increased, so in case that I want to create a new post object by `.new` with the `id` the same as `id` of `post1`, how can I do it ? Is there any way to completely wipe out `post1` from the memory ?

Comment: thank you very much, but can you tell me why Rails increased the `restore_post1` 's id by 1, though `post1` has been deleted already?

Comment: `post1.dup.save`. The `id` will be `nil` and then it will be increased by 1.MySQL does it. `id` is the primary key and auto-increment by 1. We assign the old id of `post1` for `restore_post1` to re-create the record `post1`